# How to add custom calendar.ics file to iCalendar of iphone?

Tags: iphone, icalendar

i'm trying to add a calendar.ics file to iphone's native calendar.I want to know that is it possible to do that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

you Add other library as like TAPKU Library And Use its Calender Its good look..

Comment: i dont want to use in my app to add events i just want to add in my calendars and use it from my calendars not from my app

Comment: Calendar not importing .ics

Comment: so what kind of file should be included to add a new calendar?

Answer (score -1):

I dont think that it is possible to access native ios calendar.

Comment: i dont want to access native calendar but i just want to add a new calendar

Comment: It is possible to access the native calendar through EventKit.